# multiple cc addresses for each issue

Tags: sharepoint

I am used to Bugzilla in which you can add/remove other people to the cc list for each bug, so that they get notified whenever a bug is modified.

I have to use Sharepoint's issue tracker now in which I can already set an alert to get notified upon any changes in the issue, but I was wondering if there is any way that I can create such alerts for **others**, and in particular for **multiple** people.

This [page](http://www.naumanahmed.com/2012/01/sharepoint-issue-tracking-list-send-e.html) explains how to set the issue tracker list to send an E-mail notification to the assignee when an issue is assigned to them, but sharepoint only allows one assignee.

One way is to ask people to visit the sharepoint and create the alerts for themselves, which is not really practical for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can do what you want by going to Site Settings > Site Administration > User Alerts if you are a site administrator. Here is the article that says how to do it in [MOSS](http://www.coolweblog.com/bilodeau/archives/003249.html) so I am sure you can in 2010 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a people picker field (with only one person), then create a workflow where you use this field as a CC. After that, go back to the list settings and change the people picker field to accept MULTIPLE persons, and it should work.